# Workaround for ePUB readers with mediocre CSS support?

Tags: css, epub

It seems that some ePUB readers (including FBReader 0.12.10 on Linux and PocketBook TL 3) don't understand descendant selectors in CSS.

Example:

http://wolnelektury.pl/media/book/epub/czarny-kot.epub

In FBReader all text in this book is in italic and aligned to the right. After playing with it a little I've found that to fix it I can change line 269 in `OPS/style.css` from

```
.dedication, .dedication .paragraph
{
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

to

```
.dedication
{
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Otherwise FBReader applies `text-align: right` and `font-style: italic` to all `.paragraph` elements even though there is no `.dedication` anywhere. From what I can see, it works the same way with all descendant selectors (only the last part matters). So my question is: is it possible to find a workaround (like some conditional magic) to have the ePUB work on descendant-compliant readers and give special rules for the others, so they may be worse-looking but at least not as bad as this?

Reordering might help, but it would require a lot of care to do it right.

Comment: This sounds more like an syntax issue or missed bracket issue.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by “does not appear” (except for typo that I've already fixed, OPF instead of OPS). I change the extension to `.zip`, extract it and there is `OPS/style.css` with the above fragment.
I've checked the syntax and I don't see any problem.

Comment: Apologies, just found it.

Comment: If it doesn't detect the selector separator (`,`), then you will just have to avoid combining selectors when you have repeated styles.

Comment: ...there are **multiple selectors** that include `font-style: italic`. This is why I use my own dedicated stylesheet that is as simple as possible.

Comment: @TylerH It has nothing to do with the selector separator. When I expand all combined selectors into multiple rules, the problem persists.

Comment: @Paulie_D It *is* a dedicated stylesheet. It's not very simple because it's used in an automatic converter and has to handle a lot of things.

Comment: @janek37 so `.dedication { styles } .dedication .paragraph { styles }` does **not** work?

Comment: @TylerH exactly.

Comment: @janek37 In that case there seems to be a fundamental lack of CSS support; there's not much you can do other than apply unique classes to all the elements you want to style individually. Sounds like a pain.